# nvd3 controls into 2 line

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have standart nvd3 [multybarchart](https://jsfiddle.net/aufpmb8o/1/) example 
with activate controls :

```
chart.showControls(true);
```

When screen width changed i get bad view of controls and legend , like :
[image]

is there way to fix it?

For example transform controls to two lines  like:

[image]

tried to do it with `d3.select('.nv-controlsWrap').attr("transform","translate(...,...) rotate(...)");`

but dont find way to achieve two line controls view.

thx

ps [RU_SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499794/nvd3-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8) original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be as easy as:

```
d3.select('.nv-controlsWrap .nv-series:nth-child(2)')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 25)');
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aufpmb8o/3/).

---

For "fix" it on draw:

```
function stackControls(){
  d3.select('.nv-controlsWrap .nv-series:nth-child(2)').attr('transform', 'translate(0, 25)');
}
nv.utils.windowResize(function(){
    chart.update();
    stackControls();
});    
d3.select('.nv-controlsWrap').on('click', stackControls);
d3.select('.nv-legendWrap').on('click', stackControls);    
stackControls();
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aufpmb8o/3/).

Comment: If there way to save it when i disable one or more variable in legend ( click circle on one stream)( sorry bad english)?

Comment: Thanks it great! thought about onclick event but dont know how to realize it.